# can mysql cli exit with error if no records returned?

Tags: mysql, client

I would like to execute a sql command in bash, and do something based on whether or not there was a result.

e.g.

```
$ LOOKUP=123; mysql -e \
    'SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='$LOOKUP dbname \
    && echo "Row $LOOKUP exists"
    || echo "Row $LOOKUP does not exists"
```

I can think of bodges (e.g. testing for ZLS) but wondered if there was a clean way?

Comment: Even if you find a solution that technically works this really, really feels like hitting a nail with the wrong hammer.  If you're familiar w/ shell scripting I imagine you have another scripting language up your sleeve.  Perl? Python? Php?  Use their libraries for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Agreed! But this was a one-off quick data fix. (see my comment to @RolandoMySQLDBA below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the query to force a value

Instead of

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=${LOOKUP}
```

you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE id=${LOOKUP}
```

Here is bash script to use that new query

```
LOOKUP=123
SQLSTMT="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE id=${LOOKUP}"
RCOUNT=`mysql -u... -p... -AN -Ddbname -e"${SQLSTMT}"`
if [ ${RCOUNT} -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Row ${LOOKUP} exists"
else
    echo "Row ${LOOKUP} does not exist"
fi
```

Here is an alternative

```
LOOKUP=123
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT('Row ',rcount,' ',IF(rcount=0,'Exists','Does Not Exist')) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) rcount FROM rolando WHERE id=${LOOKUP}) A"
mysql -u... -p... -AN -Ddbname -e"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/answer.txt
cat /tmp/answer.txt
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks. I went for something very similar: `while read i ; do if [[ -z $(mysql_one -A -B -N -e "SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id="$i") ]]; then echo "$i" ; fi; done <ids-list >ids-not-found`

Answer (score 2):

you can try this too as one-liner

> (( $(mysql ... -e "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE yourcondition") ))

will return 1 (error) on 0 rows and 0 (ok) on rows found.

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

Comment: Thanks MatteoBee! I like that this is succinct, however, it's not clear from reading it what is happening, unless you deal with bash all the time and are familiar with the rather quirky `(( ))`. So for the sake of [Kernighan's law](https://www.quotes.net/quote/57502) I'll stick with `[[ -z ... ]]` :-)